# Ubuntu-drivers not running during setup Lubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, ubuntu-drivers

I installed Lubuntu 22.04 yesterday but I noticed my wifi card didn't show up. I had this problem before, I reinstalled and looked for use proprietary drivers but I couldn't find it. I still tried, and it didn't show up. In software sources it asked me if I wanted to use `bcmwl-kernel-source` but I can't download it because I don't have internet. I don't know how to run `ubuntu-drivers` now with no internet I've tried with `apt-cdrom`. However, I'm using a USB and it's not working when I mount to `/cdrom` manually. Can't connect my phone to wifi via USB because my phone doesn't support wifi hotspot help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: The Lubuntu ISOs are considerably smaller than Ubuntu Desktop and many of the other *flavors* of Ubuntu, part of the reason is there are few extra kernel modules included on the ISO. The intention is post-install, you connect to internet & download all additional drivers then (*as per manual or lower down this page - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/4/4.3/software_sources.html*)